# When to add an extra "helper" table rather than running complex query

Tags: 7, database

I'm trying to build a "notification" feature into my site similar to Facebook:

I would show a little graphic with a number indicating the number of new comments to nodes a user created or commented on.

The query will probably look like this, assuming uid=1 (haven't tested yet):

```
SELECT count(node.nid) as new_comments
FROM {node} node
INNER JOIN {node_comment_statistics} ncs ON node.nid = ncs.nid
INNER JOIN {history} h ON h.nid = node.nid
WHERE ( (h.uid = 1) AND (h.timestamp < ncs.last_comment_timestamp)
AND ((node.uid = 1) OR (0 < (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM comment c WHERE c.uid = 1 AND c.nid = node.nid)) )))
```

This query would run with every page request for all logged in users which could impact performance. 
I could create a "helper" table where I keep a "new_comments" counter for each uid. For every comment added or updated I would then check which users need their "new_comments" counter incremented.

**My question:**

Is there a rule of thumb when to use such a "helper" table instead of running complex queries. Or do I need to create say a million records in Devel and test the performance of above query under full load?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As long as all your fields used in JOIN and WHERE are indexed properly, you don't really need a separate table to do this, I probably would rewrite it in a single query, sub queries tend to be slow.

If you want something intermediate (in case you have > 1.000.000 rows), you have 2 options:

1. Create a temporary table and keep it up to date using cron and/or
   hooks
2. Use caching in Drupal to remember the result and combine it
   with hooks

Both solution have pro's and con's:

1. Can be updated by cron, but has a record for every user, no matter if that user visits the site or not.
2. Needs to run the query when there's no cached data, but will be faster on a second page visit.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do anything complex, that doesn't change often, or you know / can act on when it does change, you should use the "helper" table called cache - or just create your own cache_module_name table.

A single query like what you have posted above, is probably not going to be a big deal. But if you plan on have a lot of these kind of statistics, they quickly add up, instead you can cache the rendered output and improve performance a lot.